# Cannot stop getting this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, serial-port, int

I've been working on this project for three weeks, and I am not a coding person.  I am honestly doing my best.  I've developed a respect for programmers everywhere.

At first, I tried to import a serial and do something with its contents right away, and this wasn't working.  Now, I am trying to write it to a text file, read it, and do something with it.

Either way, I cannot convert it to an integer for some reason.  This is the erro I keep getting:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I will post a bit of code for each program I am trying to make work.

import serial and do something directly code sample:

```
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import time
import re

raw_buffer = ''
ydata = []
ydata_changed = False
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=None)

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
while True:


    waiting = ser.inWaiting()
    if waiting > 0:


        raw_buffer = raw_buffer + \
                     ser.read(waiting).replace('\x00', '').replace('\n', '')
        re.sub("[^[0-9]", "", raw_buffer)


        raw = [int(x) for x in raw_buffer.split(' ,')]
```

To a text file and "back"

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
while True:
    f = open('serial.txt', 'r+')
    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    f.write(line)
    data = f.read()
    try:
        int(data)
    except ValueError:
            pass
    time.sleep(1)
    print int(data)
    f.close()
```

Same error each time.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
177,177,178,178,178,178,178,179,178,178
```

In advance, thanks for any advice you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `raw_buffer.split(' ,')` splits on `" ,"`, not `","` or `" "`, so `split` doesn't work for your data and returns `["177,177,178,178,178,178,178,179,178,178"]` which isn't a list of ints as string.

`raw_buffer.split(',')` works, even if there are spaces before/after the comma because conversion to `int` can handle that all right.

Antther issue is if your lines end with a comma, so it would generate an extra blank string that we must filter out, like this:

```
raw = [int(x) for x in raw_buffer.split(',') if x]
```

If you don't know the separator in advance, consider using regex split:

```
raw = [int(x) for x in re.split(r"[\s,]+",raw_buffer) if x]
```

Comment: I have tried both iterations.  Below are the error messages.  I am going to try it with the text file one now.

raw = [int(x) for x in re.split(r"[\s,]+",raw_buffer)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

raw = [int(x) for x in raw_buffer.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: After "import re" on the next set of code, I get the same errors:

raw = [int(x) for x in re.split(r"[\s,]+",data)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: I may have misunderstood. Can you print `raw_buffer` ?

Comment: When I print raw_buffer, (before trying to make it an integer) I get the following:

181,181,181,180,180,179,181,182,182,182,181,181,181,183,182,183,182,181,181,182,180,180,180,179,181,180,180,179,179,180,179,180,179,180,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,179,....

As soon as it hits that code you gave me, it freaks out:
  File "/home/pi/plotend2-16.py", line 30, in <module>
    raw = [int(x) for x in raw_buffer.split(' ,')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '181,181,181,180,180,

Comment: can you try to print `raw_buffer.split(',')`, that's really strange (I may have fixed an issue though)

Comment: I have also tried without the space.  For some reason, I cannot get it to recognize that these numbers can be turned into integers.  I know it is possible because I have a Processing 3 code that does it....

Comment: can you print `str(raw_buffer).split(',')` (force convertion to string before split?

Comment: So, now my code is having a bit more issues (not graphing and not liking my syntax because I switched to Python 3.5).  Is there something I can do to know if it is being changed into integers?

Comment: just `print(str(raw_buffer).split(','))` and report contents.

Comment: Alright, so I tried that and here is a sample of what comes out:

["['180'", " '179'", " '179'", " '179'", " '179'", " '180'", " '180']"]

Also, after more testing, one of the errors said that it was reading it as a list, not a string.  So, I used the following code:

plots = list(map(int, plots)

It appears to register the numbers a bit better.  :)  Does that seem like it could be what was wrong?

Comment: another last attempt: can you `print(type(raw_buffer))` and report the result. I'm lost here.

Comment: When I use that, it comes back as:  <class 'list'>.  So, I think the problem was I was trying to change a list into an integer which python does not like